# Convert html table logfile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an huge chat log file and want to convert it into a better looking printable file.
At the moment it's just a html table. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sXCNC/

```
html table
```

It should look like this at the end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv9bO.png

Any ideas how to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the HTML, you can do this with the CSS:

```
table, tbody, tr, td {display:block; border:0;}

tr.me {
    width:60%;
    background-color: #22A1CE;
    margin:0 0 .5em auto; padding:.5em;
}

tr.other{
    width:70%;
    background-color: #7F007F;
    margin:0 auto .5em 0;
}

thead, td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(8) {
    display:none;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
    float:right; font-size:.8em;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
    font-size:.8em;
}
```

end end up with [this result](http://jsfiddle.net/sXCNC/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a table.
Put each message in a div, and depending of the sender of the message, apply a class which will put some CSS rules on it, something like this:

```
.me {
 float: left;
 background: red:
}

.contact {
 float: right:
 background: green;
}
```

Comment: The program just gives me a table.